# possible to script to open multiple terminals in local machine and ssh to different servers?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh

This is what I'd like to do: 
On my local linux system (Ubuntu), I'd like to write a script which would open multiple terminals, and do an ssh to different servers (the list of servers would be in a text file which the script will read), and execute a program on each of those servers. Is this possible to do? 
So far, I've got a script which will do a ssh to different servers and execute a program on each of them, however, I am not able to "automatically" open multiple terminals - one for each server that I'm doing an ssh to.

Comment: Use [pconsole](http://www.heiho.net/pconsole/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this command:

**xterm -e /bin/bash -l -c "ssh user@destination"**

This opens a new xterm session. There must be similar steps (probably) if you are using another terminal emulator, instead of xterm.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer worked for xterm, however I'm using gnome-terminal.. 
I tried a similar command for gnome-terminal but it did not work

Comment: gnome-terminal -e "ssh user@destination" maybe?